# How to make users finish a flow on Qlipo.com songs page

Tags: website-design

Qlipo is a website targeted to help English-speakers learn to speak Spanish through Music.

The flow I'm looking for is watching the songs page -> learn vocabulary -> Take the "Test yourself" quiz.

On [www.qlipo.com/songs.php?song_id=10](http://www.qlipo.com/songs.php?song_id=10) for example, the users starts watching the video with the songs lyrics but not many pass afterwards to learn the Lyrics and take the "Test Yourself" quiz.

Any idea how to improve this funnel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the funnel you should visualuze it for users.
[image]
You could show the steps more clear.
[image]

Also adding words to a quiz by a user is a bad solution. You put too many actions and decisions to a user! Just auto-include all words in a quiz and possible let user to remove words, not to include.

To engage users implement levels, points, badges, leaderboard, i.e. gamify their learning experience. User should clear see his progress.

Comment: Thanks Alexy, You raised good points. It's important to have someone objective provide these insights.